# Error: No glance method recognized for this list

Tags: r, function, dplyr, broom, glance

I'm trying to write a function that can flexibly group by a variable number of arguments and fit a linear model to each subset. The output should be a table with each row showing the grouping variable(s) and corresponding lm call results that broom::glance provides.  But I can't figure out how to structure the output. Code that produces the same error is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

test_fcn <- function(var1, ...) {
  x <- unlist(list(...))
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(c('gear', x)))) %>% 
    mutate(mod = list(lm(hp ~ !!sym(var1), data = .))) %>% 
    summarize(broom::glance(mod)) 
}

test_fcn('qsec', 'cyl', 'carb')
```

I'm pushing my R/dplyr comfort zone by mixing static and dynamic variable arguments, so I've left them here in case that's a contributing factor. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there.

```r
test_fcn <- function(var1, ...) {
    x <- unlist(list(...))
    mtcars %>% 
        group_by(across(all_of(c('gear', x)))) %>% 
        summarise(
            mod = list(lm(hp ~ !!sym(var1), data = .)),
            mod = map(mod, broom::glance),
            .groups = "drop")
}

test_fcn('qsec', 'cyl', 'carb') %>% unnest(mod)
## A tibble: 12 × 15
#    gear   cyl  carb r.squared adj.r.sq…¹ sigma stati…² p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC devia…³ df.re…⁴
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
# 1     3     4     1     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 2     3     6     1     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 3     3     8     2     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 4     3     8     3     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 5     3     8     4     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 6     4     4     1     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 7     4     4     2     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 8     4     6     4     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
# 9     5     4     2     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
#10     5     6     6     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
#11     5     8     4     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
#12     5     8     8     0.502      0.485  49.2    30.2 5.77e-6     1  -169.  344.  348.  72633.      30
## … with 1 more variable: nobs <int>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​adj.r.squared, ²​statistic,
##   ³​deviance, ⁴​df.residual
## ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Because you are storing the `lm` fit objects in a `list`, you need to loop over the entries using `purrr::map`.

You might want to put the `unnest` into the `test_fcn`: a slightly more compact version would be

```r
test_fcn <- function(var1, ...) {
    x <- unlist(list(...))
    mtcars %>% 
        group_by(across(all_of(c('gear', x)))) %>% 
        summarise(
            mod = map(list(lm(hp ~ !!sym(var1), data = .)), broom::glance),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
        unnest(mod)
}
```

---

### Update

Until your comment, I hadn't realised that the grouping was ignored. Here is a `nest`-`unnest`-type solution.

```r
test_fcn <- function(var1, ...) {
    x <- list(...)
    mtcars %>% 
        group_by(across(all_of(c('gear', x)))) %>%
        nest() %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(mod = map(
            data, 
            ~ lm(hp ~ !!sym(var1), data = .x) %>% broom::glance())) %>%
        unnest(mod)
}

test_fcn('qsec', 'cyl', 'carb')
## A tibble: 12 × 16
#     cyl  gear  carb data     r.squared adj.r.s…¹      sigma statis…²  p.value    df logLik
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>       <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     6     4     4 <tibble>    0.911     0.867    2.74e+ 0  20.5      0.0454     1  -8.32
# 2     4     4     1 <tibble>    0.525     0.287    1.15e+ 1   2.21     0.276      1 -14.1 
# 3     6     3     1 <tibble>    1       NaN      NaN        NaN      NaN          1 Inf   
# 4     8     3     2 <tibble>    0.0262   -0.461    1.74e+ 1   0.0538   0.838      1 -15.7 
# 5     8     3     4 <tibble>    0.869     0.825    7.48e+ 0  19.9      0.0210     1 -15.9 
# 6     4     4     2 <tibble>    0.0721   -0.392    3.18e+ 1   0.155    0.732      1 -18.1 
# 7     8     3     3 <tibble>    0.538     0.0769   2.63e-14   1.17     0.475      1  91.2 
# 8     4     3     1 <tibble>    0         0      NaN         NA       NA         NA Inf   
# 9     4     5     2 <tibble>    1       NaN      NaN        NaN      NaN          1 Inf   
#10     8     5     4 <tibble>    0         0      NaN         NA       NA         NA Inf   
#11     6     5     6 <tibble>    0         0      NaN         NA       NA         NA Inf   
#12     8     5     8 <tibble>    0         0      NaN         NA       NA         NA Inf   
## … with 5 more variables: AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>,
##   nobs <int>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​adj.r.squared, ²​statistic
## ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Explanation: `tidyr::nest` nests data in a `list` column (with name `data` by default); we can then loop through the `data` entries, fit the model and extract model summaries with `broom::glance` in a new column `mod`; `unnest`ing `mod` then gives the desired structure. If not needed, you can remove the `data` column with `select(-data)`.

PS. The example produces some warnings (leading to `NA`s in the model summaries) from those groups where you have only a single observation.

Comment: Your change was perfect for generating output, thanks so much!  The follow-on problem became how to get the grouping portion recognized. Changing "group_by" to "nest_by" and "data = ." to "data = data" finally worked.  I understand the "nest_by" change but why "data = ." doesn't work is puzzling to me.

Comment: You're very welcome @Jaywalker. Not sure I entirely understand your follow-up problem. Very happy to take a look if you post a new question (provided this is still an issue?).

Comment: Apologies for being cryptic! In the example above, using group_by results in a linear model that is calculated for the entire dataset multiple times, instead of being calculated individually for each subset defined by the specified group_by factors. That is, the lm results are identical for any gear/cyl/carb combination. I'll definitely post a follow-up question as I'm a little mystified as to why group_by didn't work here.

Comment: @Jaywalker Apologies for responding so late; I've made an edit to fix the grouping issue (hadn't realised this earlier until you mentioned it). Please take a look.

Comment: I very much appreciate your circling back and clarifying the mechanics of it all. Thank you!